# use of finite geometry to construct MOLs

Tags: combinatorics

Can someone cite an elementary text to help me understand the use of finite geometries in constructing mutually orthogonal latin squares? Take for example the following from Wikipedia? "The parallel class structure of an affine plane of order n may be used to construct a set of n - 1 MOLS." I understand the terms, but that is all.

Answer (score 1):

The wiki article is probably referring to Bose's theorem: A complete set of mutually orthogonal latin squares of order $n$ exists if and only if an affine plane of order $n$ exists. The proof may be found in standard books on design theory, such as *Combinatorial Designs: Constructions and Analysis*
By Douglas Stinson.

Comment: Perfect: that's exactly what I was after.